# in need to some help to solve this problem "The method 'addListener' was called on null."

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

the error:

> The method 'addListener' was called on null.
> Receiver: null
> Tried calling: addListener(Closure: (dynamic) => dynamic from Function 'addtemp':.)

my code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Temp3 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Temp3State createState() => _Temp3State();
}

class _Temp3State extends State<Temp3> {
  double fenTemp = 0.0, celTemp = 0.0;
  var temperature = ['Fehergeit', 'Clecsies', 'Kalvin'];
  String selctedTemp = 'Fehergeit';
  String selctedTemp1 = 'Clecsies';
  var fenController;
  var celController;
  var kalController;
  bool isFen = true;
  controller(String temp) {
    var s;
    switch (temp.substring(0, 1)) {
      case 'F':
        fenController = TextEditingController();
        s = fenController;
        break;
      case 'C':
        celController = TextEditingController();
        s = celController;
        break;
      default:
        kalController = TextEditingController();
        s = kalController;
    }
    addtemp(s);
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    fenController.addListener(addtemp);
    celController.addListener(addtemp);
    kalController.addListener(addtemp);
  }

  addtemp(var s) {
    switch (s) {
      case 'F':
        fenTemp = double.parse(fenController.text);
        celTemp = convert(fenTemp, true);
        if (isFen) celController.text = celTemp.toString();
        isFen = true;
        break;
      case 'C':
        setState(() {
          celTemp = double.parse(celController.text);
          fenTemp = convert(celTemp, false);
          if (!isFen) fenController.text = fenTemp.toString();
          isFen = false;
        });
        break;
      default:
        celTemp = double.parse(celController.text);
    }
  }

  // fenListener() {
  //   fenTemp = double.parse(fenController.text);
  //   celTemp = convert(fenTemp, true);
  //   if (isFen) celController.text = celTemp.toString();
  //   isFen = true;
  // }

  // celListener() {
  //   setState(() {
  //     celTemp = double.parse(celController.text);
  //     fenTemp = convert(celTemp, false);
  //     if (!isFen) fenController.text = fenTemp.toString();
  //     isFen = false;
  //   });
  // }
  // kalListener(){}

  double convert(double temp, bool isF) {
    return isF ? (temp - 32) * (5 / 9) : (temp * (9 / 5) + 32);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Temperature 3'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: Center(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    DropdownButton(
                      items: temperature.map((item) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem(
                          child: Text(item),
                          value: item,
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      onChanged: (newValue) {
                        setState(() {
                          selctedTemp = newValue;
                        });
                      },
                      value: selctedTemp,
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      controller: controller(selctedTemp),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Enter temperature',
                        suffixText: selctedTemp.substring(0, 1),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 40,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    DropdownButton(
                      value: selctedTemp1,
                      items: temperature.map((item) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem(
                          child: Text(item),
                          value: item,
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      onChanged: (newValue) {
                        setState(() {
                          selctedTemp1 = newValue;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      controller: controller(selctedTemp1),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Enter temperature',
                        suffixText: selctedTemp1.substring(0, 1),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

how can i solve it :

> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Builder:
> The method 'addListener' was called on null.
> Receiver: null
> Tried calling: addListener(Closure: (dynamic) => dynamic from Function 'addtemp':.)
> The relevant error-causing widget was:
> MaterialApp
> lib\main.dart:11

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize before calling addListener:

```
initState() {
    super.initState();

     fenController = TextEditingController();
     celController = TextEditingController();
     kalController = TextEditingController();

    fenController.addListener(addtemp);
    celController.addListener(addtemp);
    kalController.addListener(addtemp);
  }
```

also don't forget to call `dispose()` on them